# Is (x+1/4) equivalent to x/4?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am struggling with basic algebra and it is severely interfering with my problem solving ability for the class that I am currently in (Calculus 2).

Is (x + 1/4) the same as x/4?

Or does x turn into x/1 + 1/4, and then I multiply x * 4/1 * 4 to get 4x/4 + 1/4 which would equal to 4x+1/4?

I am so confused please help.

Comment: The answer to your first question is definitely **no**; I'm not sure how you got rid of the $+1$. Your second solution is probably correct, but it's hard to tell because you didn't format it properly (please check [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) link); if you meant $$ x + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{4x + 1}{4}$$ then yes, you're right.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just recently joined and did not know how to format it properly, I appreciate the help!

Comment: @A.J. Display equations in comments! I guess I never even thought to try it.

Comment: @Josh - People will sometimes let you get away with bad typesetting the first time. But you should probably learn at least the basic MathJax for your next post.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Okay! I'll be sure to read that link and properly typeset the next time I have a question

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Only recently learned it was possible myself when I saw it someone else's comment; I rarely use it, but here it felt like the formatting was particularly important.

Comment: @A.J. - Exactly. That's the reason why I wrote it as an answer instead of a comment. Live and learn, I guess.

Comment: Just some advice: if you're struggling with basic algebra in such an advanced class, I recommended reviewing basic algebra techniques as much as possible right now so that you won't fall further behind. As someone who used to be a student assistant for those types of classes a little over a year ago, I've seen people struggle with basic fractions and trigonometry which wasn't good because calculus requires a basic foundation of those concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty hard to know exactly what you're asking, as you're not using the math typesetting features of this site, but

$$x+\frac{1}{4} = 
\frac{4x}{4}+\frac{1}{4} =\frac{4x+1}{4}$$

which seems to be your second option.

I have no idea how you would come to think that it equals $\frac{x}{4}$, unless it was the only way you could get to the next step in some derivation. In which case: no, that's not it. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Thank you!! I meant to ask it in the way you formatted it, another user has also pointed it out and the both of you have helped to clarify it for me. 

Comment: @Josh, if you think this answers your question please mark it as an answer.